# Use esp-01 relay with Nodemcu possible?

Tags: nodemcu, relay

I'm building a simple mobile controlled relay switch. however, I'm out of relay modules, but I do have these esp-01 relays: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1VIKLeJLO8KJjSZFxq6yGEVXaW.jpg

I'm wondering if these can work with a nodemcu? So far no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "work with a nodemcu"? You mean, can you connect a NodeMCU to them, or can you plug an ESP-01 into them and communicate to them with a NodeMCU?

Comment: the relay is on io 0 or io 2 of the esp-01 so give the relay board power and try to connect io 0 or io 2 with a resistor to ground or 3.3 V pin on the header  (the yellow header has the esp-01 pinout of course)